# Why use Telerik instead of Crystal Report or build in RDLC

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, telerik

What are the advantages of Telerik over others (Crystal Report, RDLC) for asp.net app?

Comment: Should this really be tagged with Crystal, as opposed to SSRS, BIRT, Jasper, Cognos, etc?

Comment: BIRT, Jasper, Cognos; are those widely used with asp.net.  For me I have never tried and usually I used Crystal, RDLC or SSRS for my asp.net applications.

Comment: Aren't there enough of these types of questions on SO, especially related to CR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a summary page with features definition and key benefits at the following page:

http://www.telerik.com/products/reporting.aspx

As for me, I prefer a report tool from DevExpress component vendor:

http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Reporting/

I especially like a newly introduced “Barcode” feature:

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument1313